# Tensorflow onehot encode

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm new at using tensorflow and have some questions about tensorflows one hot encoding.

I want to read an CVS file in which in which the last column represents the labels. Labels are integer values from 1 to 7.

I want do to classification using the softmax model.

Therefore I need my labels to be in an onehot tensor format?

Is there a simple way/tensorflow built-in to convert my labels into one hot?

According to the tutorial for file parsing I have the following code for parsing my csv but the part of one hot encoding is missing.

```
def read_from_cvs(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TextLineReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
    record_defaults = [[] for col in range((num_attributes))] # no defaults, all values must be given
    attributes = tf.decode_csv(value, record_defaults=record_defaults)
    features = tf.stack(attributes[1:-1])
    labels = tf.stack(attributes[-1])
    return features, labels

def input_pipeline(filename = 'dataset.csv', batch_size = 30, num_epochs=None):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filename, num_epochs=num_epochs, shuffle=True)
    features, labels = read_from_cvs(filename_queue)

    min_after_dequeue = 10000
    capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size
    feature_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [features, labels], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
        min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
    return feature_batch, label_batch
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`tf.one_hot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot)

```
# depth = num_clasess in general for the problem     
labels = tf.one_hot(tf.stack(attributes[-1]), depth)
```